# Which payment processors do not allow for chargeback?

Tags: payment, fraud, money, chargeback, sell-bitcoins

I would like to receive a payment for selling my bitcoins. I don't trust the person much, so I will ask for money in advance. However, I'm not sure which payment processors could I use for such a transactions that are chargeback-resistant. I know PayPal is bad for this, but what are my other options?

Which payment processors do not allow for chargeback?

Answer (score 6):

It's a short list.

- Cash
- Liberty Reserve (though they did freeze some customer funds recently until they became verified)
- Bank Wire (though see comment below)
- Webmoney (supposedly)

Here's the payment methods hardness list:

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Payment_methods

Comment: Do note that bank wire transfers can be reversed if the recipient account has not been credited - sometimes up to 2 days later. Always wait for the balance to appear in your account before acting.

Comment: Also, banks can reverse *any* transaction from your account if they have a reason for it - for example if they made a mistake - even after it has appeared in your account and even after you've spent the money, leaving you with negative balance in your account. You can trust your account balance only in nominal situations.

Answer (score 4):

[Liberty Reserve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberty_Reserve) (which was closed in May 2013) doesn't allow charge backs.

Answer (score 1):

- Payza
- Skrill
- Paytoo
- Neteller
- Coinbase (Bitcoin, but has some sweet business tools for selling)